# Component const is different in function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am trying to create a paypal order, the data1 information is correct in the component, but in createOrder function it is always empty, I am new to react maybe there is something simple I am missing ? I am using react-vite btw

Github link : https://github.dev/LegendTaker/Madona

code:

```
import { PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import { useShoppingCart } from "../context/ShoppingCartContext";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function PayPalPayment() {
  const serverUrl = "http://localhost:8888/";
  const { getCartItemsInfo, clearCart, getCartTotal } = useShoppingCart();
  /*const [items, setItems] = useState<object[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartItems = getCartItemsInfo();
    setItems(cartItems);
  }, [getCartItemsInfo]);

  was trying a fix with useEffect dosen't work :( 

  */
  const description = "Pizza madona anjou";
  const value = getCartTotal().toString();
  const items = getCartItemsInfo();
  const data1 = {
    value: value,
    items: items,
  };
  console.log(data1);
  const createOrder = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data1);
    return fetch(`${serverUrl}my-server/create-paypal-order`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product: {
          description: description,
          cost: data1.value,
        },
        itemsFE: data1.items,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((order) => order.id);
  };

  const onApprove = (data: any) => {
    return fetch(`${serverUrl}my-server/capture-paypal-order`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderID: data.orderID,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status === "COMPLETED") {
          close();
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const close = () => {
    clearCart();
  };

  return (
    <PayPalButtons
      createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data)}
      onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data)}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: screenshot of logs]

for some reason the items in my context appear as empty when in dev tools it shows it isn't, if i refresh the page and try again it works.

Comment: What's in `useShoppingCart`?

Comment: Also, if you could create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kare-h7tx6k?file=/src/App.tsx), that would probably help a lot.

Comment: I will start creating a minimal example good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had to force rerender the paypalButton with the value